# Google Firebase "Follow these steps to migrate an existing site with zero down-time."

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

"Follow these steps to migrate an existing site with zero down-time."

(Provide token on existing domain
Open your registrar and enter the following TXT records)

It asks for this in the advanced options in domain verification.
What exactly is this?
Should I add?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.